# What should be the result after fld

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x87

I need to calculate what will be the value of x after this code.

```
Section data
db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0x80,0,0x40

Section text
Fld tword [x]
```

The answer should be 8 but I got 3.

`Sign: 0`

`Mantisa: calcukated from the part of 0x40 0 which is 1000000000000000 give us after calculate : 2`

Then we get 1.5 from the fraction code

And the result is 1.5 * 2 = 3

Answer (score 4):

For starters you mixed up the naming, what you call the mantissa is the exponent. It's encoded with a bias of 16383. So your exponent is `16384 - 16383 = 1`. The significand is stored with an explicit integer bit, so that's simply `1` as well.

The number is thus `1 * 2^1 = 2`. It's not 8 as you claim. You can check it in a debugger:

```
(gdb) info float
=>R7: Valid   0x40008000000000000000 +2
```

Comment: Thank. Can you explain why there is no fraction? What about the 80 which is part of the fraction

Comment: The extended precision format explicitly stores the integer bit, so the `0x80…00` is `1.000…00` in binary. Single and double precision omit the integer bit which is assumed to be `1` so in that case you only have fraction.